# Symfony3: Select total of orders for each month

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, query-builder

I'd like to display a chart that contain the total of orders for each months.
Right now the data in the controller are **static (50,20,12,33,19,21,42,30,5,17,9,28)**.

My question is how to create a query to select the total of orders for each month and put the result in the the series data dynamically

```
entities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Order')->totalOrders();
    // Chart
$series = array(
    array("name" => "Number of orders",    "data" => 50,20,12,33,19,21,42,30,5,17,9,28)
);

$months = array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');


$ob = new Highchart();
    $ob->chart->renderTo('linechart');  // The #id of the div where to render the chart
    $ob->chart->type('column');
    $ob->title->text('Chart Title');
    $ob->xAxis->title(array('text'  => "Horizontal axis title"));
    $ob->xAxis->categories($months);
    $ob->yAxis->title(array('text'  => "Vertical axis title"));
    $ob->yAxis($series);
    $ob->series($series);
```

I don't know how to do it in the query_builder

```
public function totalOrders()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->select('COUNT(o)')

        ->groupBy(''); //group by month


    return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

**Entity**

```
/**
* Order
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\OrderRepository")
*/
class Order
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
 */
private $date;
//..............
```

Comment: Where is the info on your Doctrine Entities? Without that, it's hard to help you...

Comment: @AlvinBunk  I have edited my question

Comment: Just to be clear, do you need to ignore the years? So, the January orders count should contains orders for January 2015 and January 2016?

Comment: @MassimilianoArione :  Yes I need to ignore the years